# Pixel Value of 0 is not Black?

Tags: java, pixel

I'm programming a rendering system for a 3D game, and I'm rendering pixels through an `int` array, appropriately called `pixels`.

In the `render()` method of my `Screen` class, I first do this, to clear all previous pixels :

```
for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    pixels[i] = 0;
}
```

This should make all the pixels black, but it instead doesn't really seem to do anything, and all previous pixels are still there. I tried doing -1, and that made it white, removing all previous pixels. I don't really know what's going on.

How do I set the pixels to black? If you need more code from the classes, tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: what is your pixel format? if ARGB or RGBA, you have alpha channel included, thusly value 0 is fully transparent color. This is just a guess.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't really know what other code to show, and I don't want to post all the code. What other information do you need?

Comment: @kajacx Oh, right, that's it. Whoops, thanks!

Comment: @kajacx: my hats off to you. 1+. Please post an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I do realise that the question is difficult to answer, I just wasn't really sure what information I should post. Sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

As requested, i post this as answer. If your pixel format is `RGBA` for example (expecting 8 bits for each channel), then value 0 is fully transparent black, while -1 is fully visible white.

For fully visible black use `255` (or `0xFF`).

If your format is `ARGB`, then you need `255 << 24` (or `0xFF000000`) to properly set the color channel bits.